# Relevance of the ฯ character

Tags: keyboard, special-chars

I've noticed that there's a seemingly Thai character (ฯ) on page 2 of my Android special characters keyboard. I couldn't find any reference to the character's usage outside of Thai orthography, but I assume it must have some broader usage if it's important enough to merit its own key. Could someone illuminate its typographic significance for me?